# Erro na função de formatar data

Tags: javascript

tenho essa função:

```
function formatarData(data) {
      var d = new Date(data),
        mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        dia = '' + d.getDate(),
        ano = d.getFullYear();

      if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
      if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

      return [ano, mes, dia].join('');
    }
```

e nela consigo brincar e formatar a data do jeito que eu quiser, porém quando eu coloco data dia 01 e mês 01, ele subtrai 1 ano, 1 dia e 1 mês:

exemplo: passo a data 01/01/2018 e retorna 20171231.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que está errado e como concerto isso?

Comment: Como vc está passando a data pra função?

Comment: Ao passar `formatarData('01/01/2018')` está retornando normal: `20180101`

Comment: @dvd passando por input type date, o dado vai como "2018-01-01"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso porque o `input data` está enviando o valor no formato:

```
2018-01-01 // aaaa-MM-dd
```

Me parece que `new Date()` está tratando o hífen como sinal de subtração. Substitua o hífen por outro caractere (pode ser uma vírgula ou uma barra):

```
2018-01-01 => 2018/01/01 ou 2018,01,01
```

Basta você fazer um `replace`:

```js
function formatarData(data) {
   data = data.replace(/-/g,"/"); // troca o '-' por '/'

   var d = new Date(data),
     mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
     dia = '' + d.getDate(),
     ano = d.getFullYear();

   if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
   if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

   return [ano, mes, dia].join('');
}

$("input").trigger("focus");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2018-01-01" onfocus="console.log(formatarData(this.value))">
```